# Personalisation strings with default values

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder

Can we add a default value to a personalisation string (in this case, %%FirstName%%) without 'transforming' it into AMPscript code or adding a default value in the sendable data extension which contains the FirstName column? I know those 2 ways I mentioned will yield the end-result I need, but we're just exploring a third option if such exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider adding a default value to the personalization string in Email Studio?

[image]

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll try that way because this feature is not available beyond the data extension creation process. tnx